# is Process.Start() synchronous?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, process

I have a code like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi= new ProcessStartInfo(...);
Process process = Process.Start(psi);
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

even so the `process` have the process information of the application (i have logs) in rare cases on the production computer the process is not opened at all.

As I now Process.Start() is synchronous and if it returns a value there must be a running process.

Another information that I have is that the genuine process is also the shell process.

Does anyone have an idea what is the problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say directly below the code.

Comment: I think he means to say although the app logs show process being not null, sometimes he cannot see the process appearing in the OS

Comment: "the process is not opened at all." - are you sure of that? Or could it be that the process starts and immediately shuts down, without displaying any information about that fact? As it is, you've not shown us enough code for us to help you.

Comment: The new process was not opened because I have log writes when it starts and have none.

Comment: That does not mean anything.  A process can easily be started correctly but *not* make it to whatever code you wrote that creates the log entry.  It can crash before that and you will be unaware of that since you didn't do anything to record the Process.ExitCode.

Comment: Do the current process and the newly started process share the same logs? If so, how is the logging done? Are you using a library or is it a self-built logging framework?

Comment: They do not share the same log file (a new one but it was not created). the main() code path ensures log/window will be reached

Answer (score 2):

Process is IO artifact, so there are always some delays, between you start it and it actually opened.

This delay, naturally, depends on concrete machine, where you run your code.

So, like a solution you can

- or sleep main thread untill the `p` process opened, for some amount of time
- or close the main thread, only when from (say) some timer you are able to find required `p` process in the list of already run OS processes.

The second, I think, is a better solution.